# Is that possible to assign a type to this (cucumber world object)

Tags: cucumberjs

Is that possible to have the completion with **this** world object ?
I mean...

I have a class named Application

```js
export class Application {

  constructor() {}

  async run() { 
   // do stuff to run the app
  }

  get applicationDescription(): string {
    return 'The best application in the world';
    }
}
```

In my step

```js
Given('I run my application', {timeout: 10000}, async function() {
   this.app: Application = new Application();
   await this.app.run(); <-- here when I write this.app. I want to see that run is a 
                             accessible method
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In the most basic sense, `this` is world within a step definition (you must NOT use arrow functions, as you have shown):

```
Given('I run my application', {timeout: 10000}, async function() {
   this.app = new Application();
   await this.app.run();
});
```

When done in this fashion you are just monkey patching properties onto the world object, so its working on the basis that its type is `any`, so you don't get type safety/autocomplete in your IDE.

You can use a custom world to get those benefits:

```
class MyWorld extends World {
  app: Application

  constructor(props: IWorldOptions) {
    super(props)
  }
}

setWorldConstructor(MyWorld)

Given('I run my application', {timeout: 10000}, async function(this: MyWorld) {
   this.app = new Application();
   await this.app.run();
});
```

Note that the first param in the step function is `this: MyWorld`, which is allowed in typescript to provide a type override for the `this`.  It must come before any other params.  If you omit it, `this` is still typed as Cucumbers `World` so you're back to `any`.

Comment: Although this points in the right direction, for me the ```this: MyWorld``` needs to be as a parameter of the function implementing the Step itself. So with this signature:
```Given('I run my application', {timeout: 10000}, async function(this: MyWorld)```

Comment: @jonypera Quite right, I'll edit to clarify